# how to select a particular row from a table?

Tags: perl

I want to know how to select a particular row from a table, shown in a gadget.

On automating am getting the following code:

```
use strict;

use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;

my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                                    port => 4444, 
                                    browser => "*chrome", 
                                    browser_url => "http://10.102.163.3/" );

$sel->open_ok("/admin_ui/svm/html/main.html");
$sel->click_ok("//table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img");    
$sel->click_ok("//input[\@value='Yes']");
```

Can anyone please explain the following line in the above coding?

```
$sel->click_ok("//table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img");
```

Also, am getting the same recording, every time when i select a row and delete.

Can anyone please explain how to check for a particular value as shown in the above snapshot and then select that row and delete it?

Please explain me with code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> **Can anyone please explain the following line in the above coding?
>
>   `$sel->click_ok("//table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img");`**

`$sel` is a reference to an object of type Test::WWW::Selenium

`->click_ok()` invokes the `click_ok` method of that object.

The argument to this method is a [locator](http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.25/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm#Element_Locators)

`"//table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img"` is an [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) expression that specifies the HTML element to be acted on.

`//` indicates that the locator type is an xpath expression.

`table[1]` specifies the first occurence of a table (where there may be several successive tables)

...

`td[2]` specifies the second occurence of a table data element.

The other parts should be obvious. Overall it specifies an image in the second column of a nested table.

---

(Update)

> **Can anyone please explain how to check for a particular value as shown
>   in the above snapshot and then select that row**

To select a `tr` that contains an element with an attribute named `value` with a value of `"Yes"` you can use

```
//*[@value="Yes"]/ancestor::tr
```

---

I use the following code to test xpath expressions

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = <<END;
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td><input value="Yes" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td><a href="/woo.html">Woo</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
END

my $xpath = '//*[@value="Yes"]/ancestor::tr';


my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);
my $n = 0;
for my $node ($doc->findnodes($xpath)) {
  print ++$n, ': ', $node->toString(), "\n";
}
```